# How to delete a JSON array from a JSON object?

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, rad-studio

I have a JSON file with content:

```json
{"chapters":[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "name": "1"
  },

  {"id":"2",
    "name": "2"
  },

  {"id":"3",
    "name": "3"
  },

  {"id":"4",
    "name": "4"
  },

  {"id":"5",
    "name": "5"
  },
  {"id":"6",
    "name": "6"
  }
],
  "1": [
    {
      "name": "1.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "1.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "1.3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can read values from an array, add and change values in an array, but I don't know how to delete an array from the JSON object. For example, I want to delete the array named "1". How can I do it?

Comment: `TJSONObject` has a [`RemovePair()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.RemovePair) method.

Comment: If you want to delete the array only then the object property `"1"` will continue to exist. Are you sure you don't want to delete the whole property (what `RemovePair()` does)?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Oh,yea,thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by below code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  _JSONStr = '{"chapters":[{"id":"1","name": "1"},{"id":"2","name": "2"},{"id":"3","name": "3"},{"id":"4","name": "4"},{"id":"5","name": "5"},{"id":"6","name": "6"}],"1": [{"name": "1.1"},{"name": "1.2"},{"name": "1.3"}]}';
var
  AJSONVal: TJSONValue;
begin
  AJSONVal := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(_JSONStr);

  if AJSONVal is TJSONObject then
    (AJSONVal as TJSONObject).RemovePair('1');
end;
```